# Problems that occur when you subtract the time set to text cells in Excel

Tags: python, excel

I would like to know the reason why the following value comes out when calculating the time difference between the two cells in Excel. Also, I would like to ask if Python can express it as follows.
[image]

Comment: That would seem to be the wrong result.  Are you sure that the `Start` and `End` values you show are in `B2` and `A2`? I would have expected `0.0146759259259259`  or `00:21:08` depending on the formatting.